# What movies are associated with "2046"?

Tags: story-identification

There is a Chinese movie called "2046" that takes place (partially) in 2046.  But I think that there are also one or two movies that are associated with this one.  Not sure if they're in the future or not.  Does anyone know what they are?

Comment: As a programmer, I'm bothered by the fact that it isn't 2048. ;)

Comment: @gnovice: Same here. I had to restrain myself from "correcting" it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*2046*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2046_%28film%29) is a 2004 sequel to two previous films [*Days of Being Wild* (1990)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Days_of_Being_Wild) and [*In the Mood for Love* (2000)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Mood_for_Love). Although the film contains science fiction elements, it appears to primarily be a love story that continues some of the story arcs of characters from the first two movies (which are set in the 1960's).

Comment: Ack!  Don't know why I couldn't find this myself, but for whatever reason, I wasn't finding it.  Of course, as soon as I post it, and get a response, it's trivial to find!  I attribute this to good karma from your correct answer.

Comment: @Beska: Making stuff easier to find is SE's objective, so it's no wonder it becomes easier to find once it was posted here. `:)`

Comment: Highly obscure tidbit: in 2001, three years before _2046_ came out, Faye Wong (who plays Wang Jingwen, a former real-life stage name of hers) made what I suspect is probably an indirect reference to the movie on her eponymous album _Faye Wong_. In the song _Bāt Mìhn Fēihàahng_ (‘Sleepless Flight’), describing someone who can’t fall asleep on a plane for thinking about a lover, one of the remedies tried is “Sou dou i-ling-sih-cat” or “Counting to 2047”.